# Why not work with numbers greater than 10 digits?

Tags: c, rsa, primes

Hello community I have the following problem The following code does not converge to any solution for numbers exceeding 10 digits, and do not know where the problem can be as knowing that the number is prime would be met Fermat's little theorem in one call function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long exp_mod(unsigned long x, unsigned long y, unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long s,t,u;
    int i;
    s=1; t=x; u=y;
    while(u) {
        if (u&1) s=(s*t)%n;
        u>>=1;
        t=(t*t)%n;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(){
    unsigned long number,a,b;
    int i;
    printf("introduce number to test\n");
    scanf("%lu",&a);
    number=a;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    while (1) {
        a=rand()%(number-1)+2;//0<a<number
        b=exp_mod(a,number-1,number);
        if ( b==1 ) {
            printf ("by Fermat:  %lu is prime\n",number);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? regards

Comment: The maximum value for an `unsigned long` in C on a 32 bit machine is `4,294,967,296`.

Comment: unsigned long long needed see ranges for different types as listed in the table at URL  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: @RichardChambers Thanks for answer, i'm use gcc for linux sorry i suspect 'll use pointers

Comment: @JohnBut should accuses segmentation fault or StackOverflow to suspect that the data type is out of range

Comment: Use a bigint library like GMP

Comment: the Precedence of + is higher than %  so the line: 'a=rand()%(number-1)+2;' becomes: 'a=rand()%(number+1);'  Probably not what you actually want to do.   And what happens of the number supplied by the user is NOT prime?   The code loops forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the code then the proposed solution for you thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gmp.h>

main()
{
 mpz_t b;
 mpz_init(b);
 int escero;
 unsigned long numero,a;
…
 printf("Introduzca el numero a testear\n");
 scanf("%lu",&a);
 numero=a;
 srand((unsigned int)time(0));
 mpz_t A,P,P1;
 mpz_init(A); mpz_init(P); mpz_init(P1);
…

 while (1) {
        a=rand()%(numero-1)+2;//0<a<numero
        mpz_set_ui(A,a);
        mpz_set_ui(P1, (numero-1) );
        mpz_set_ui(P,numero);
        mpz_powm( b, A, P1, P);//b=exp_mod(a,numero-1,numero);
        //gmp_printf("a^p-1 [mod p] = %Zd\n",b);
        if ( !mpz_cmp_d(b,1) ) {
…
         printf ("%lu es testigo por Fermat de que %lu es primo\n",a,numero);
         break;
         }
        }
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks again community !!

Comment: Don't just dump the code, but write something additionally. You could for example write your own version what the problem was and what your code accomplishes. StackOverflow should be a library of good content, so everybody should describe the reasoning behind their answers.

Comment: thanks for your advice, you're very kind, I'll edit the question and the solution is more well understood my problem and as solutions. regards

Answer (score 2):

The on most compilers and systems, the size of `unsigned long` is 32 bit, so it's about 4 * 10^9 - so that's why it can't handle numbers that have 10 digits. 
Just change `unsigned long` to `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: Change the code to unsigned long long int and still does not work, I suspect I use pointers